# Context menu does not open on first click

Tags: c#, contextmenu, show

I have a C# application where I dynamically populate, then launch a context menu called cmTestplan.

```
    private void cmTestplan_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((cmTestplan.SourceControl is TextBox) && 
        (cmTestplan.SourceControl.Enabled == true) && 
        (cmTestplan.SourceControl.Text != ""))
        {

            RightClickSetup(cmTestplan.SourceControl.Text);
            cmTestplan.Show();
        }

    }

    private void RightClickSetup(string Path)
    {
        this.UseWaitCursor = true;
        cmTestplan.Items.Clear();

        //Test for file or folder
        if (Directory.Exists(Path) == true)
        {
            cmTestplan.Items.Add("Open folder");
            this.UseWaitCursor = false;
        }
        else if (File.Exists(Path) == true)
        {
            cmTestplan.Items.Add("Open folder");
            cmTestplan.Items.Add("Open file");
            this.UseWaitCursor = false;
        }
    }
```

For some reason (that I hope one of you fine ladies or gentlemen may be able to provide) the menu does not display on the first time I right-click on a text box with which this cmTestplan is associated.  It will display consistently thereafter on a single right-click.

I've tried commenting out all the file/folder checking and still get the problem.

Comment: Try putting a static menu and see if it displays correctly. If so, try adding back your dynamic logics in small chunks to see exactly what's breaking the event-chain (it smells like an exception, but I don't see anything that could throw it). Also, set a breakpoint at the start of your event and check if the properties your conditional is based on all have the expected value.

Answer (score 8):

Your menu does not open since the event argument cancel is default true for an empty menu.

simply add `e.Cancel = false;` in your Opening event handler;

```
   RightClickSetup(cmTestplan.SourceControl.Text);
   e.Cancel = false;
```

.. you can also skip the "show" call.

See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229625.aspx)

Comment: This is one of those things that makes sense AFTER you know it, but kicks your butt until you figure it out.  Thanks.